# In an OLS regression, will excluding all data for a non-reference category of a dummy variable impact the other dummy level categories?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, categorical-encoding

Say I have an OLS regression with a dummy variable level A, B, C and D, where A is the reference category. Will the estimated coefficient value and/or statistical significance of B or C change or be impacted if I remove from the input data set all of the data mapped to D and re-run the regression (which will no longer contain dummy variable level D)?

On the values changing or not, I would think not because the coefficients of B and C simply reflect the difference between the mean of B and C, respectively, and the mean of A (the reference).

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: this question may help https://www.quora.com/Do-you-include-all-dummy-variables-in-a-regression-model

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by 'dropping' to judge whether Noah's answer or mine is correct. I interpret you to mean that you are fitting the model after removing all data labelled D.

Comment: @mkt makes a good point that I had not thought of. This could mean two different things.

Comment: Good point. I reworded the question. @mkt interpretation of the original question is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I interpret what you are doing as removing all data associated with the label 'D' from the dataset before fitting the model. This is distinct from relabelling 'D' to 'A' or some equivalent step, which is Noah's assumption.

---

It depends on whether you have any other variables in the regression. If you do not, then your interpretation is correct. Dropping D will not affect the intercept (A), or the coefficients for B or C.

But imagine you also have an additional variable that you are using as a predictor. If the distribution of this continuous variable is non-random with respect to D vs. A, B, or C (i.e. they are associated in some way), then dropping D may also change the coefficient for the additional variable. This change may also affect the coefficient estimates and associated p-values for A, B, or C if they are associated with the additional variable.

Comment: Thanks. You mention "It depends on whether you have any other variables in the regression", you seem to imply this would only matter if the 'other variables' are continuous. But what if I have another dummy set, it's not clear to me why the levels of this second dummy set would be impacted.

Comment: @StatsScared Whether it is continuous or categorical does not matter. I was using continuous for ease of illustration, but have removed that detail now.

Comment: @mkt, thanks for the response. However, I am still unclear on whether the coefficients for B or C will be impacted - both values and statistical significant - if D is dropped and the regression includes a continuous variable and/or another dummy set (one that is different from A, B, C, D).

Comment: @StatsScared Coefficients and p-values may well be affected in the situation you describe, but one cannot say exactly in what way. That's because it depends on the strength and nature of the association between the predictor variables. I've edited my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: @mkt Thanks. I guess a side question is how would two sets of dummies be related to one another so that there is some association between them? I thought this 'association' would only take place if there was an interaction between levels of each dummy variable set.

Comment: @StatsScared I'm not sure I understand your question. Imagine a variable with X, Y, and Z levels. A from variable 1 happens to co-occur frequently with X of variable 2. There's your association.

Comment: @mkt Imagine I regress sales on two sets of dummy variables: city and items. City has levels A, B, C and D (each corresponds to a different city) and items corresponds to levels X, Y and Z (each corresponds to a different item). If A is the reference for city dummy variable set, why would the coefficients B or C change if data for D is removed from the input data. I can see, however, how X, Y and Z coefficients could change in this case (but again, not B or C)

Comment: I suggest reading a bit about [tag:multicollinearity]. If data for D is removed, it would change X, Y, and Z. But estimates of X, Y, and Z are not independent of estimates of A, B, and C. So those estimates can shift too. This depends in part on model specification too (e.g. is there an interaction term in the model?)

Comment: @mkt thank you, I removed my downvote. I misunderstood the question. I agree with your analysis.

Comment: @Noah No worries! I agree with yours in the situation you describe.

Comment: Thanks, @mkt. I may be side-tracking the discussion here, but can there be (im)perfect collinearity among categorical dummy variables that is strong enough so that removing a level in the first set of categorical dummy variables would impact the estimated coefficient for the second set of categorical dummy variables? (Maybe this question requires its own thread..)

Comment: @StatsScared Yes, that's what I meant by [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428287/in-an-ols-regression-will-excluding-all-data-for-a-non-reference-category-of-a/428288?noredirect=1#comment799339_428288)

Comment: @mkt. Great, thanks for clarifying. Another question if I may, hopefully final. Under what conditions would removing a level in the first categorical variable set *not* impact the estimated coefficients in the second set of categorical dummy variables?

Comment: @StatsScared Hmmm. I think it should not change anything (1) if you don't have any other variables in the model, or (2) if you do have other variables but have included an interaction term in the model.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: OP clarified their question, so this answer does not apply. This answer responds to the question of simply removing the dummy variable for category D from a regression that contained the full dataset.

---

Dropping categorical D is equivalent to relabeling all D's as A's. This will absolutely affect your intercept and coefficients for the non-reference categories. The intercept will now be the mean of those in categories A and D combined, and the coefficients on the non-reference categories will be the difference in means between the corresponding category and the combined A and D group. The only reason it would make sense to do this would be if you wanted to assume that the means for categories A and D were equal. If they were equal in the population, you would have some increased precision in your estimates. If not, you will have biased estimates for the true coefficients.